# Why using mask-image with svg, the svg overlap every component?

Tags: css, svg, icons, background-image, mask

i'm using svg icons with mask-image property in scss, the icons looks great, but the only problem that i'm having it's, when the icon is under another component, the icon overlap all.

Here is the code:

```
    .icon {
      display: inline-block;
      mask-position: center;
      mask-repeat: no-repeat;
      mask-size: 100% auto;
      mask-image: url("~@/assets/images/icons/Icon-search.svg");
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      background: $grey-blue;
    }
```

Example with search icon (SVG)

[icon normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeOMc.png)

[icon overlaping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiqyQ.png)

This overlapping happen with all the svgs. I'm using chrome and happen too with firefox.
Safari doesn't have this problem.

I'm using Vuejs 2.
Thanks.

Comment: i think that header should be relative and z-index:9999;

Comment: That problem isn't happening only with the header, is like the images have infinite z-index and you can't put anything above them